# $_POST variable staying the same

Tags: php, post, directory

I'm having trouble with this code and using different emails to view images in a directory (processed/$email) and the email changes per user's respective form entry, yet only shows the images from the most recent folder created regardless of the email given.

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="POST">
E-mail:
<input type="text" name="email" id="email2"><br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Retrieve" name="submit"><br><br>
</form>
```

and  here's the PHP:

```
<?php
function scanDirectoryImages($directory, array $exts = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png'))
    {
    if (substr($directory, -1) == '/') {
        $directory = substr($directory, 0, -1);
    }
    $html = '';
    if (
        is_readable($directory)
        && (file_exists($directory) || is_dir($directory))
    ) {
        $directoryList = opendir($directory);
        while($file = readdir($directoryList)) {
        if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
            $path = $directory . '/' . $file;
            if (is_readable($path)) {
                if (is_dir($path)) {
                    return scanDirectoryImages($path, $exts);
                }
                if (
                    is_file($path)
                    && in_array(end(explode('.', end(explode('/', $path)))),   $exts)
                ) {
                    $html .= '<a href="' . $path . '"><img src="' . $path
                        . '" style="max-height:250px;max-width:250px" />  </a>';

                }
            }
        }
        }
        closedir($directoryList);
    }
    return $html;

}

echo scanDirectoryImages(processed.$_POST['email2']);
   ?>
```

I've tried unsetting variables, etc. It doesn't work. When I go back to the form from any page, it's still only showing the most recently uploaded folder of images. The only thing that will make it show new images is if there is a new directory. I feel like I must be approaching this fundamentally wrong somehow and I'm new to PHP so some help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: You have the `id` and `name` mixed up ~ you should use the `name` in the posted variable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original function has a recursive nature to it but doesn't utilise the existing suite of `recursiveIterator` classes - hopefully the below will be of use in that respect. When I tried your original function all I got it to return was a folder name and not a list of files / images.

```
function scanImageDirectory( $directory, $root, $exts=array('jpg','jpeg','png','gif'), $exclusions=array('bmp') ){
    $html=array();

    $dirItr = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $directory );
    $filterItr = new DirFileFilter( $dirItr, $exclusions, $directory, 'all' ); 
    $recItr = new RecursiveIteratorIterator( $filterItr, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST );

    foreach( $recItr as $filepath => $info ){
        if( $info->isFile() && in_array( strtolower( pathinfo( $info, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) ), $exts ) ) {
            $filename=str_replace( array( realpath( $root ), chr(92) ), array( '', chr(47) ), realpath( $info ) );
            $html[]="<a href='{$filename}' target='_blank'><img src='{$filename}' alt='{$info->getFilename()}' /></a>";
        }
    }
    return implode( PHP_EOL,$html );
}



$dir=ROOT.'/images/css/icons/browsers';
$root='c:/wwwroot';

echo scanImageDirectory( $dir, $root );
```

Or, as example for your situation

```
$dir="processed/{$_POST['email']}";
$root=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
echo scanImageDirectory( $dir, $root );
```

I realise that the class `DirFileFilter` is one I wrote and not a native PHP class - this can only be described as an `id-10-T` error.. Apologies - here is that class.

```
class DirFileFilter extends RecursiveFilterIterator{

    protected $exclude;
    protected $root;
    protected $mode;

    public function __construct( $iterator, array $exclude, $root, $mode='all' ){
        parent::__construct( $iterator );
        $this->exclude = $exclude;
        $this->root = $root;
        $this->mode = $mode;
    }

    public function accept(){
        $folpath=rtrim( str_replace( $this->root, '', $this->getPathname() ), '\\' );
        $ext=strtolower( pathinfo( $this->getFilename(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) );

        switch( $this->mode ){
            case 'all': 
                return !( in_array( $this->getFilename(), $this->exclude ) or in_array( $folpath, $this->exclude ) or in_array( $ext, $this->exclude ) );
            case 'files':
                return ( $this->isFile() && ( !in_array( $this->getFilename(), $this->exclude ) or !in_array( $ext, $this->exclude ) ) );
            break;
            case 'dirs':
            case 'folders':
                return ( $this->isDir() && !( in_array( $this->getFilename(), $this->exclude ) ) && !in_array( $folpath, $this->exclude ) );
            break;
            default:
                echo 'config error: ' . $this->mode .' is not recognised';
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public function getChildren(){
        return new self( $this->getInnerIterator()->getChildren(), $this->exclude, $this->root, $this->mode );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm a little confused because you have an unused variable ($dir). Also I tried your function and it doesn't display the images in a directory I type into the form after correcting the other variables (you edited these in as I typed this!)

Comment: I edited it because I spotted the mistook in your code - it took a while as I'm still half asleep but you used the id rather than the name ( POST vars use the name ) - I have this working ok having built a directory structure to accomodate email addresses etc

Comment: Still not working on http://98.117.55.190/myimageshandle.php and everything below the form using your code is gone (should be some paragraphs below, you can see on the other pages), lol
http://i.imgur.com/F0yjsbS.png is what i'm looking at right now and I'm baffled

Comment: in your call to the function you are using `$directory` rather than `$dir` so there would errors appearing in the log about undefined variables I guess. I obviously cannot test your form as my email wil not be in the system

Comment: We found that at the same time, I just corrected it but no fix :( http://i.imgur.com/mqqzP5W.png

Comment: are the folders being created? I just uploaded an image to test

Comment: Yup! http://98.117.55.190/processed/esme.weatherwax@lancre.com/composition9136HgD.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118729/discussion-between-ramraider-and-dylan-moore).